# Triggering on-screen touch keyboard on custom control in C

Tags: c, winapi, user-controls, winapp

I'm writing a C win32 application that has a custom text box input with `onFocus`/`onBlur` callbacks. This control cannot be changed and I cannot use C++.

As you could guess, I'd like the on-screen touch keyboard to appear `onFocus` and to disappear `onBlur`. What's the best way of achieving that? 
I was thinking of creating an invisible textbox over it or something along those lines, thinking the OS would trigger the OSK if needed? Should I use UI Automation? I struggle to find C examples of such implementation

Regards